# Hide SubTabs on load Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

```
Private Function SetBt()
    Dim Ax As Single
    Ax = CSng(Right(Me.ActiveControl.Name, 1))
     For i = 1 To 7
         Me("B" & i).BackColor = Box0.BackColor
     Next
        Me.ActiveControl.BackColor = Box1.BackColor
        Me("P" & Ax).SetFocus
        LB0.Caption = Me("B" & Ax).Caption
     ' Show SubTab
            Dim PageNameDigitLen As Integer
            PageNameDigitLen = Len("P" & Ax)
            For J = 0 To SubTab.Pages.Count - 1
                If Left(SubTab.Pages(J).Name, PageNameDigitLen) = Me("P" & Ax).Name Then
                  SubTab.Pages(J).Visible = True
                Else
                    SubTab.Pages(J).Visible = False
                End If
            Next J
End Function
```

I have a form with tabs and subtabs.  I have several command buttons.  When I click on a command button various tabs and subtabs are visible, other not.

I would like the subtabs to be not visible on load.

I can make the subtabs not visible on load SubTab.Visible = False, but then the command buttons will not work.  I tried making a command button enabled on load Me.B1.Enabled = Yes that did not work.

D

Comment: AFAIK, if Tab control is visible, at least one page must be visible. Can set Tab control as not visible. Should not impact buttons as long as they are not on tab pages. Where are they located?

Comment: The SubTab tabs have captions, so are visible, Style=visible.   The bottons are on a form.  I think the issue is the function is set up to run on setfocus.  I've tried to setfocus to the first command button B1 and to enable it, but both do not work.    I'd be ok setting one tab to visible.  I'm going to have several subtabs, but want them all invisible on load or only one.

Comment: How did you design tab with subtabs?

Comment: I followed the directions on a youtube video and modified for my needs.  Main tab control on left and another tab control on the right. I can upload it, if I'm able. I'm not fond of the way the cmd buttons get their color, but  that's for another day.

Comment: Could post in a forum that allows attaching files. I am not following that description. I have never tried this.

Comment: Maybe a better way to do it, would be to have a form open when I click on one of the command buttons.  The form could be a form with tabs.  Then set it to close when another command button is clicked etc.. Then the main form with it's tabs could be my main form.  Programmatically this might be easier.

Comment: Could even set SourceObject property of a subform container control. This emulates behavior of a Navigation Form.